# Update-ca-trust fails with p11-kit not permitted to write file on Centos

Tags: centos, ca

sudo update-ca-trust force-enable fails with the following error -

> p11-kit: couldn't complete writing file: /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt: Operation not permitted
>
> p11-kit: couldn't complete writing file: /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: Operation not permitted

Machine Details -
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)